# Function to invert key,value to value,key in dictionary is not working

Tags: python

I'm a Python newbie trying to write a function that inverts a dictionary. The function works as expected (inverts the dictionary passed in as an argument) on a visualizer tool but doesn't work when I try to run it in the actual test environment. Please can anyone help me spot the bug?

```py
def invert(my_dictionary: dict):
    temp_dict = {}

    for key, value in my_dictionary.items():
        temp_dict[value] = key
    
    my_dictionary = temp_dict
```

Comment: Can you provide an example that shows it doesn't work? Maybe you meant to return the dictionary instead of reassigning it in the local space of the function?

Comment: How are you calling this function? Do you realize that whatever dict you pass to that function will stay unchanged? All you do is assign the ***local variable*** of the function to a new dict. The passed argument from outside the function will not be affected

Comment: `my_dictionary` which you pass in the function param will not be inverted, only the `my_dictionary` within the function would be inverted.

Comment: You need to actually return the new result and do `new_dict = invert(d)` or actually modify the passed argument, like `my_dictionary.clear() ; my_dictionary.update(temp_dict)`

Comment: @Tomerikoo. I didn't realize my_dictionary was a local variable!!! my_dictionary.clear();my_dictionary.update(temp_dict) did the trick. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Jay, thanks a lot for the input. I need to be more careful with local and global variables.

Comment: @gmdev, thanks a lot. The tests state that the function shouldn't have a return type but must alter the dictionary passed in as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, your code takes an argument, does some operations and assign a value to the argument. But, nowhere are you returning the value back to the main program. In the visualizer, your argument might be passed as a reference to the original dictionary and hence assigning something to argument updates the original dictionary as well.
so instead of

```
def invert(my_dictionary: dict):
    temp_dict = {}

    for key, value in my_dictionary.items():
        temp_dict[value] = key
    
    my_dictionary = temp_dict
d={'a':'b'}
invert(d)
```

use

```
def invert(my_dictionary: dict):
    temp_dict = {}

    for key, value in my_dictionary.items():
        temp_dict[value] = key
    return temp_dict
d={'a':'b'}
d=invert(d)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The tests explicitly state that the method should not return a new dictionary. The function must alter the original dictionary.